# MySQL REGEXP integer comparison

Tags: mysql, regex, comparison

I'm using REGEXP to match specific strings out of a ton of text in a `LONGTEXT` column. For example:

```
Text text text text text
 text text text text text
 text text SOLD: 75/101 text
 text text text text text
```

So my queries have been looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `file` REGEXP
'SOLD:[ ]{1}[0-9]{1,2,3}/[0-9]{1,2,3}'
```

Which would properly match the `SOLD: 75/101` string.

But is it possible, to do a comparison on the numerator? Such as, find all `SOLD: >=75/101`?

The comparison number would be a user inputted number via $_POST. I know that REGEXP isn't really meant for comparing numbers, but is there some way to maybe *capture* the string with regexp, then perform a comparison on the integers some other way?

Comment: You can create stored procedure to encapsulate any logic

Comment: Would you only have to consider fractions like `76/101` and `123/101`, or would you also have to take `70/80` into account (which is greater than `75/101`, of course)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, I'd have to consider those first two also. I'm not interested in comparing the fraction as a whole, just the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have to look at the numerator, as stated in your comment, then

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP 
"SOLD: ([1-9][0-9]{2,}|[8-9][0-9]|7[5-9])/101";
```

should work.

By the way, `[0-9]{1,2,3}` is a syntax error in most regex flavors (I don't know how MySQL handles it); the correct way to specify a range is `[0-9]{1,3}`.

Comment: What is the user inputted $_POST value was 80 or 90 though?

Comment: Ah, right. I hadn't read that part thoroughly enough. Sorry, MySQL regexes don't support capturing groups, so I guess you really have to use a custom function for that. Unfortunately, I don't know MySQL well enough to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Norse: That means "2 or more".